# Can Xv6 guarantee the write syscall is atomic?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

It would cause serious problem that a user program try to write the large data to a file by a write system call.

```c
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user/user.h"
#include "kernel/fs.h"
#include "kernel/fcntl.h"

void main()
{
    int fd = open("TEST2", O_CREATE | O_RDWR);
    char buf[((10-1-1-2) / 2) * BSIZE + 10] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < ((10-1-1-2) / 2) * BSIZE + 9; i++) {
        buf[i] = 'x';
    }
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    write(fd, buf, ((10-1-1-2) / 2) * BSIZE + 10);
    exit(0);
}
```

It's fine if nothing happend.

[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74480681/153655172-161f11a9-db09-4034-bbc8-2c0610a86d63.png)

[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74480681/153655211-64bbd50d-23f2-4cc7-a4e4-69b78ea4a14a.png)

If a crash happend after the first loop before the second.

[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74480681/153655001-0c53ed3a-c87d-45fe-b961-a6e91017a2da.png)

[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74480681/153655385-44d1a02d-a57c-4ea9-933c-fca0cec9972a.png)

The `TEST2` file is existing and it's 3072 bytes.
Despite the fact that xv6-book claims that each syscall promises their writes would be atomic, the implementation cannot guarantee that the write syscall is atomic.

[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74480681/153655941-3420c76b-d90e-483b-a8bd-ffa291881146.png)

Comment: You already note that the documentation says that `write()` is atomic.  That's consistent with POSIX requirements, too, though I'm unsure whether Xv6 claims POSIX conformance.  So what are you actually asking?  Does it have something to do with whatever information you've stuck in those images?  (Hint: don't use images except where necessary to convey information that is inherently graphical.)

Comment: Speculation: your doubts, whatever they are, may arise from an incorrect expectation of what it means that `write()` is "atomic".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm not sure if write() is atomic in [xv6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv) and other operating systems. What happens if we have a crash when writing 500GB of data to the disk using a single write? Is the file made up of both old and new parts? (thx for your patient :)

Comment: When POSIX or (I presume) xv6 says that `write()` is atomic, it does not mean that the call has no effect when it fails, and it certainly is not talking about behavior in the event of a system crash.  It is talking about atomicity with respect to system calls by other threads.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I got it! thank u